# How to convert stereo sound to mono with FFmpeg?

Tags: c++, function, audio, ffmpeg

I use the FFmpeg library for a personnal project and I need help about one thing. I have a music file in stereo sound and I want to convert this stereo sound to mono sound ? Is it possible with this library ? Is there a function inside to do this job ? My project is in C/C++.

I searched on the Doxygen documentation on the FFmpeg website and on this forum but I didn't find something interesting.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: As i remember there is no function, but you can easily convert it yourself by calculating both streams together.

Comment: Do you have any piece of code to give by example ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `swr_convert` from libswresample to convert between formats. Something like:

```
#include "libswresample/swresample.h"

au_convert_ctx = swr_alloc();

out_channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO;
out_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
out_sample_rate = 44100;
out_channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(out_channel_layout);

in_sample_fmt = pCodecCtx->sample_fmt;
in_channel_layout=av_get_default_channel_layout(pCodecCtx->channels);

au_convert_ctx=swr_alloc_set_opts(au_convert_ctx,out_channel_layout, out_sample_fmt, out_sample_rate,
            in_channel_layout, in_sample_fmt, pCodecCtx->sample_rate, 0, NULL);
swr_init(au_convert_ctx);
//Generate your frame of original audio, then use swr_convert to convert to mono,
//converted number of samples will now be in out_buffer.
int converted = swr_convert(au_convert_ctx, &out_buffer, MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE, (const uint8_t **)&pFrame->data , pFrame->nb_samples);
//...
swr_free(&au_convert_ctx);
```

to get you started. This will convert whatever the original format happens to be to 44100 kHz mono. You could also use `pCodecCtx->sample_rate` as the output sample rate as well.

It's the most flexible and easiest solution.

Answer (score 101):

You can just use ffmpeg. Direct command is present for the purpose-

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.flac -ac 1 mono.flac
```

Would convert your stereo file into mono channel. For more details, you can look at this page-

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot! Btw, if anybody else needs to convert bulk of files in a row, like I did:

`find . -name '*.mp4' -exec ./convert.sh {} \;`

Comment: Then, inside the `convert.sh` file:

Comment: `ffmpeg -i $1 -ac 1 $1.mono.mp4`

Comment: @MarcoArruda You can skip the `convert.sh` file by invoking `ffmpeg` directly with: `find . -name '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i '{}' -ac 1 '{}.mono.mp4' \;`

Comment: This makes loud sections clip a lot. Is there a way to flatten it w/o clipping

Comment: Note that `-ac 1` will **mix down** both stereo channels to a single mono one, which might not be what you want, especially if it’s just “a mono source erroneously recorded in stereo”. In that case, throw one of the channels away like this: `ffmpeg -i INPUT -filter_complex '[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL[left]' -map '[left]' OUTPUT` (replace `INPUT` & `OUTPUT` of course). This will select the left channel, if you want the right one, use `FR` and `[right]` instead.

Comment: `Unsupported channel layout "1 channels (FL)"`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, you could resample it yourself. It depends on what you already have and what format you use. I cannot give you code which would work instantly, but give you an example (pseudo/real code mix).

After you encoded the frame, and have done the things you have to do, your data buffer will be filled with the audio. Now it depends how your format is (see [here](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/group__lavu__sampfmts.html#gaf9a51ca15301871723577c730b5865c5)) and how many channels you have. Let's assume it is signed 16bit stereo, than your buffer would look like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| LS1 | RS1 | LS2 | RS2 | ... |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
// LS = LEFT SAMPLE 16 Bit
// RS = RIGHT SAMPLE 16 Bit
```

Now iterate through the buffer and calculate left and right sample together.

```
for(int i=0; i<sample_size; i+=2) {
    auto r = (static_cast<int32_t>(buffer[i]) + buffer[i+1]) / 2;
    buffer[i] = buffer[i+1] = r;
}
```

Comment: this just isn't a good strategy, the numbers in an audio signal aren't just numbers they represent a signal which involves the change in those numbers more than those numbers themselves... like if you had a sine wave where left and right were out of phase 180 degrees you would just have no signal in the mono mix down.